# Link OpenSSL to CLion on Mac

Tags: macos, openssl

When i type

```
brew install openssl 
brew link --force openssl
```

I want to link this library to my CLion project, but if force ling don't work, how am i able to link it? 
All i want to do is just `#include <openssl/evp.h>` in my CLion project.
What is the default include folder in clion?

Answer (score 1):

To link OpenSSL in the `CMakeLists.txt` add the following lines depending on the version of OpenSSL installed via `brew`:

```
include_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/include/)
target_link_libraries(openss_hmac /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.a)
```

The `include_directories` should make the `#include <openssl/evp.h>` find the header files without compilation issues.

`target_link_libraries` links the library, the above links `libcrypto.a`, i assume you want to use the cryptographic functions from OpenSSL

Answer (score 0):

try “brew list openssl”,you will see the default include folder